# Why is a semiannular region not simply connected?

Tags: vector-analysis, greens-theorem, euclidean-domain

In a textbook I am consulting re: Green's Theorem, they illustrate with the following example:

> Evaluate $\int_C y^2\, \text{d}x + 3 xy \, \text{d}y$, where $C$ is the boundary of the semiannular region $D$ in the upper half-plane between the circles $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 4$.

The first line of the solution says

> Notice that although $D$ is not simple, the $y$-axis divides it into two simple regions.

**But I don't see how the semiannular region isn't simple**: I don't see any closed curve within $D$ that could not be continuously shrunk to a point without passing outside of $D$. What am I missing?

The remark doesn't seem to play any role in the rest of the solution: they solve exactly as I would, but I'd still like to understand this claim about the domain.

Comment: What is a "simple" region? Does "simple" mean the same as "simply connected"? If the author meant "simply connected" why wouldn't he just say "simply connected"?

Comment: @bof this was exactly my own confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the author is talking about Type I and Type II (also known as $x$-*simple* and $y$-*simple*) regions used to define regions for integration with Green's theorem, i.e. regions of the form $\{(x,y) \mid a \leq x \leq b, f(x) \leq y \leq g(x)\}$ and $\{(x,y) \mid f(y) \leq x \leq g(y), a \leq y \leq b\}$, and not about it being simply connected.

If this is the case, what was meant by this sentence was:  *Although the region is neither $x$-simple nor $y$-simple ...*

Comment: as in "$y$-simple$" vs. "$x$-simple" - of course! I understand that this might be clear for someone who knows what to expect, but it seems very poorly phrased for an explanatory text! Have proposed an edit to address the ambiguity in the author's language (your answer made sense, but I didn't immediately make the connection to the author's choice of the word "simple"). Thank you kindly for your help!